# pass shell variable into awk's patern search

Tags: awk, gawk

In a script I want to search connections established between some ports gathered with another command and set on PORT variable and specific systems.

the PORT variable is pass to awk using -vp=${PORT}

but I don't know how to use "p" it inside the rest of the pattern.
his does not work:

```
$ lsof -i -P|awk -vp=${PORT} '$(NF-1)~/vm7.+:'$p'->(vm9|vm11).+ESTABLISHED/{print $(NF-1)}'
$ lsof -i -P|awk -vp=${PORT} '$(NF-1)~/vm7.+:'p'->(vm9|vm11).+ESTABLISHED/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: This isn't related to your problem but FYI when you don't put a space between `-v` and the variable it's setting (e.g. `-vp=`) you make your script unnecessarily gawk-specific. Just always include a space for portability: `-v p=`. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you as right now you're collecting answers on how to fix the syntax for your current approach but I'd bet there's actually a better solution than your current approach if we could just see your input and expected output. It's really an XY Problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
awk -v p="$PORT" '{pat="yourHost(or whatever):"p}$(NF-1)~pat{print $(NF-1)}'
```

- build the pattern(`pat`) with `p` and check the field `(NF-1)`
- you don't need (shouldn't have) the `ESTABLISHED` in pattern, since it is the last field `NF` instead of `NF-1`

Comment: "pattern" - Aaarghhhh!!!!!! Some day I'll find out who is telling people to use the word `pattern` instead of `regexp` or `string` or `condition` or whatever else they really mean and then there will be a reckoning... :-).

Answer (score 0):

Use `match`:

```
$ awk -v p=$port 'match($(NF-1),"vm7.+:" p "->(vm9|vm11)"){print $(NF-1)}'
```

There might be some errors as there was no test material. Removed the `ESTABLISHED` as it is in `$NF`, not `$(NF-1)` (in my systems, at least).

... or don't:

```
$ awk -v p=$port '$(NF-1) ~ "vm7.+:" p "->(vm9|vm11)" {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Today I learned something.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh wow. All this time using `match` when mixing vars with regex.